# Horizontal scroll-bar with unknown number of child-elements and a fixed-width parent

Tags: html, css

To clarify the Title:

I have a div, which has child-elements with a unknown fixed-width (I used bootstrap for mobile-friendly users) and I want these child-elements to be in a container where I can scroll horizontally.

Found something similair: http://jsfiddle.net/kh5k7/1/

The only problem is, that the parent has an assigned width (320px), while mine might change.

Of course I know that giving it a width of 1000000px, nothing will likely not fit in it, but I would like it to be user-friendly and working 'fluidly'

Comment: [SO] deals with programming questions.

Comment: Please refer to the [help/on-topic].

Comment: But it says webapps right here...

Comment: Yes, _using_ web apps. Not developing them, as per the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 4):

Use `width:100%;` for parent `div`

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/kh5k7/279/)